# Problem with DAC with current mirrors

Tags: operational-amplifier, current, dac, mirror

I'm trying to design curent steering DAC with binary weighted inputs - I'm using M4, M5, M6, M7 to copy the reference current flowing in M8 with coefficients of 1,2,4,8. The idea is to put either 0 or 1 to the drains of M4, M5, M6, M7 and use them as switches. After that I sum all the currents from the current mirrors at the resistor R1 and It's working as it is. Now, comes the problem.

At the right side I made a simple two stage op amplifier which I'm trying to use as current to voltage converter. I want to convert the sum of Im4, Im5, Im6, Im7 into Vout voltage equal to one of the sixteen possible input states - from 0000 to 1111. Actually, I don't know how to do that. As far as I understand the op amp.. whatever voltage I apply to the gate of M22 that is what is flowing in M18. So, my question is how to bias M22, so that I can be able to get the equal current to input combination of 4 bits. The other question is how to make the feedback. It should be a resistor and Vout = -Iout*R. And how to simulate the op amp to see that everything is properly working.

[image]

Comment: That circuit is really hard to read - can't you produce a circuit without all the text all over it and maybe black lines on a white background. You know, something that is readable without having to open the picture in a fresh tab and magnify it?

Comment: Some key parameters on the transistors are missing, principally W/L. Turns these settings on and repost.

Comment: This looks like Tanner Tools, is it?  if so turn on the setting to print black on a white background in the print menu.